# Implement nested rows in td

Tags: html, html-table

I want to implement nested rows in td with full length but I am unable to achieve it.

```
<td>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">I am nested in a table column</td>
            <td  colspan="3">I am also nested in a table column</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td colspan="3">I am nested in a table column</td>
            <td  colspan="3">I am also nested in a table column</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</td>
```

Below is the screenshot what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Here is the screenshot what it is appearing on my end:

[image]

Can you provide me some suggestions?

Comment: What is going wrong? So far you have two columns (in theory 6) over two rows.

Comment: Number of `<td>` tags should be same in each `<tr>`. You can leave a <td> empty if you don't want anything to in that place. So, for the rows where two columns are empty, add two `<td></td>` lines in the `<tr>`.

Comment: @kchason, I have attached screenshot what it look like on my end.

Comment: @thisisbobbs , I have tried but UI not look similar. I am too slow in CSS

Comment: Ultimately, to achieve the first screenshot, you have to create multiple rows for the same device, using what @thisisbobbs said. What does CSS have to do with the blank cells?

Comment: @techyaura make sure you keep the attributes in the empty `<td>` tag. e.g. from your above code, your empty `<td>` tags should look like: `<td colspan="3"></td>`

Comment: Yeah, I have dono figure that but still UI not good, may be I have to use some css to figure it out.

Comment: can you add the html snippet to your question

Comment: Thanks @guys, but yet no result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks fo the answers. But as I was implementing it in angular js. So finally I did like below:

```
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat-start="row in events | orderBy : '-created_at'">
    <td>

    </td>
    <td>000</td>
    <td>0000</td>
    <td>            
        <a ng-show="!row.expanded" ng-click="row.expanded = true;">Expand</a>
        <a ng-show="row.expanded" ng-click="row.expanded = false;">Collapse</a>
    </td>
    <td>111</td>
    <td>111111111</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>
        3333
    </td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="property in row.properties" ng-repeat-end="" ng-if="row.expanded">
    <td colspan="3"></td>
    <td>3232</td>
    <td>2323</td>
    <td>3232</td>
    <td colspan="2">2323</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<td>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
             <td>I am nested in a table column</td>
        </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>I am also nested in a table column</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>I am nested in a table column</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>I am also nested in a table column</td>
          </tr>
    </table>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take reference of this snippet. You'll find and understand what you are looking for:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">Head1</td>
            <td colspan="3">Head2</td>
            <td colspan="3">Head3</td>
            <td colspan="3">Head4</td>
            <td colspan="3">Head5</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">I am nested in a table column</td>
        <td colspan="3">I am nested in a table column</td>
        <td colspan="3">I am nested in a table column</td>
        <td colspan="3">I am nested in a table column</td>
        <td colspan="3">I am also nested in a table column</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3"></td>
        <td colspan="3"></td>
        <td colspan="3">I am nested in a table column</td>
        <td colspan="3">I am nested in a table column</td>
        <td colspan="3">I am also nested in a table column</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="3"></td>
        <td colspan="3"></td>
        <td colspan="3">I am nested in a table column</td>
        <td colspan="3">I am nested in a table column</td>
        <td colspan="3">I am also nested in a table column</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">I am nested in a table column</td>
        <td colspan="3">I am nested in a table column</td>
        <td colspan="3">I am nested in a table column</td>
        <td colspan="3">I am nested in a table column</td>
        <td colspan="3">I am also nested in a table column</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

PS: This is your complete `<table>`.

Comment: I know this is copying OP's logic, but if everything is `colspan="3"`, what's the point?

Comment: @thisisbobs he wants to have table inside <tr>